# How can I find and delete all files in subfolders by matching part of the file name

Tags: windows

Windows 10. Photos stored by month like this:

Photos > Year > Month

For example, the photos for December 2011:

Photos > 2011 > 12

There are duplicate files of nearly every photo like this:

IMG_3257.JPG

IMG_3257 (1).JPG

How can I search the entire Photos directory and remove the duplicates containing ' (1)' in the file name? Like this one:

Photos > 2011 > 12 > IMG_3257 (1).JPG

Comment: Do you know if these are exact duplicates or just files named similarly?

Comment: Yes, they are exact duplicate images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome aboard, Jay :-)

If you want a GUI based solution, then:

- download the excellent (and free) [Double Commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/)
- install (or use the portable version) and run it
- navigate to the top directory, beneath which you have your pictures
- press Alt+F7 (or use menu item Commands/Search)
- enter `(1)` as the file name (or `*(1).jpg`, or even `*(*).jpg`)
- when shown the results, click on the button "feed to listbox"
- press Ctrl+A to select all
- press F8 to delete them

If that sounds like a lot of work, it's because I detailed it step by step. In practise, a few seconds will see it done, and you will find Double Commander to be much more useful than the built in Windows Explorer :-)

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly. Very simple and it looks like it will come in handy for many other uses in the future.

Comment: It has become my desktop, since you can add your own menus & also buttons to the button bar, so you can launch all programs from there. Great for searching, copying/moving, also reading & creating archives, plus FTP, favourite directories, directory history, use Ctrl+T to add a tab, so you can have multiple directories open & tons more. Have a good dig around and it will be your power tool (also take a look at the Ditto clipboard manager, Google to find the last free version of the FastStone screen capture utility & maybe look at the Executor program launcher; these are all my must haves :-)

Comment: And, whenever you are looking for a new application, please do visit us at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: that DoubleCommander is a great tool thanks for the pointer and instructions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [DEL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/del) command to delete files containing `(1)` in the name from current directory tree.

```
 DEL /Q /F /S "*(1)*"
```

*Step by Step Instruction:*

Step 1: Navigate to your `Pictures` folder.

Step 2: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>F4</kbd>

Step 3: Type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Step 4: Type or Copy and past the command `DEL /Q /F /S "*(1)*"` or `DEL /Q /F /S "*(*)*"` depending on your requirement and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

*Parameters*:

- `/F` Forces deletion of read-only files.
- `/S` Deletes specified files from the current directory and all sub
  directories. Displays the names of the files as they are being
  deleted.
- `/Q` Specifies quiet mode. You are not prompted for delete confirmation

You may use the below parameter to prompt for confirmation before deleting a file.

- `/P` Prompts for confirmation before deleting the specified file.