# How can I delete every text file in a directory that contains a specific string using a Batch file?

Tags: command-line

I'd like to delete log files that contain 'Result'. How can I do that using a Batch file?

Edit: the string 'Result' is in the files' contents not in their name.

Comment: Is the text string in the file name, or in the file contents?

Comment: I posted a non-batch answer, using the excellent and free Double Commander [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1390051/how-can-i-find-and-delete-all-files-in-subfolders-by-matching-part-of-the-file-n/1390072#1390072) which can be used for both the fiel name and its contents.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt / batch file, use the command:

```
del *result*
```

This will delete all files in the directory with "result" in its name.

Answer (score 0):

The following will delete any files ending with `.log` in the `c:\logs folder`.  Modify as necessary

```
for /F"delims=;" %%a in ('findstr /m /i "Result" c:\logs\*.log') do (
@echo %%a
del %%a
)
```